# Adding a button next to each comment

Tags: wordpress

I am making a wordpress plugin that would add "report this comment" button. For its completion, I need to add a "report" button next to every comment on a wordpress page. Although I can't find a sollution for that.

I have tried this:

```
add_filter("comment_id_fields","my_submit_comment_message");

function my_submit_comment_message($result){
    return $result . " <span>(TEST)</span>";
}
```

But that just adds a text/button/etc. to the end of the post.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to add a button to each comment by following code:

```
add_filter('comment_text', 'AddButton');

function AddButton($content){
    $comment_id = get_comment_ID ();
    $comment_text = get_comment_text(); 

    $report_button = "<form action='CommentReport.php' method='get'>";
    $report_button .= "<input type='submit' name='Report_Button' value='Report Comment: 
    $comment_id' style='background-color: orange; color: black';/>";
    $report_button .= "</form>";
    $report_button .= "</br>";

    $new_content = $report_button;
    $content = $content . $new_content;
    return $content;
}
```